Lipschitz approximation of the identity in metric spaces
Let $(X,d)$ be a complete and separable metric space and let $Y \subset X$ be a sigma compact subset. Does there exist a sequence of functions $(T_\epsilon)_{\epsilon>0}$ such that

$T_\epsilon: Y \to Y$ and $T_\epsilon(Y)$ is compact for every $\epsilon>0$;
$T_\epsilon$ is $(1+\epsilon)$-Lipschitz continuous for every $\epsilon>0$;
$T_\epsilon(x) \to x$ as $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ for every $x\in Y$?

For example if $X=Y=\mathbb{R}^d$ the projection on the closed ball of radious $1/\epsilon$ would do the job. Is this doable in every metric space?

Infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces (or Banach spaces in general) are not $\sigma$-compact, by Baire category theorem (any countable union of closed sets covering the space must contain a closed ball in at least one such set, which would imply the ball is compact, and the space is finite-dimensional).

Thank you for your comment. Of course you are right. The truth is that I am dealing with a sigma compact subset of a complete and separable metric space. I modified the question accordingly.
